# Affect on speed of wordpress membership plugins -- currently trying s2member

Tags: plugins

I'm taking a look at s2member -- I have it running, and my site is very slow -- it's taking on average about 9 or 10 seconds to load.

This is the site: http://richardclunan.net

I want to figure out if the s2member plugin is causing it to be slow. And whether there are other faster membership plugins...

3 questions:

1. Are there particular settings or things specific to s2member that I should take care of to ensure s2member doesn't make my site slow?
2. If I deactivate the plugin to test the speed of the site with the plugin deactivated, will that mean I'll have to respecify s2member settings when I reactivate it? After it's reactivated will members' accounts work ok?
3. Anybody have observations on s2member or other wordpress membership site plugins and their affect on site speed?

Comment: Can you disable the plugin to compare page load times? Might want to rule it out right off the bat.

Comment: i've done that a few times now - seems to be faster with plugin disabled, then i re-enable it, and the site stays faster, then after a while it seems to slow again... unless those results are just chance...

Comment: I've been using s2member on a few client sites for a year or two now I'd guess. Never seen or heard of performance impacts from this plugin. But anything is possible.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Plugin Performance Profiler](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/p3-profiler/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you disable a plugin (don't delete it), the settings should be preserved for when you reactivate it.

s2member and other membership plugins are pretty complicated and may cause performance issues... especially if you are on shared hosting or a host that severely limits the # of simultaneous database queries. If you manage the server yourself, increasing the MAX_CONNECTIONS property for MySQL can often help with stuff like this. (e.g. if your host limits simultaneous queries to 100 and you typically have 80 queries, but 280 with s2member activated, your page loads will be 3x as long.)

The other performance issue to think about with membership sites is that having pages different based on membership level breaks any caching you may be doing. So maybe you have good load times because of caching, and when s2member is enabled, your site can't be cached anymore.

Here are some plugins to help you troubleshoot performance issues with WordPress:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/p3-profiler/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-queries/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/blackbox-debug-bar/

FWIW, I'm the developer of Paid Memberships Pro, a competing membership plugin for WordPress. (It's totally free in the WordPress repository: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/)